# PowerPoint 2010/VBA: Add shape to group/ShapeNodes.Insert-Methode - how can I get X2/Y2 and X3/Y3?

Tags: vba, shapes, powerpoint-2010

As far as I know there is no direct way to add an shape to an existing group.
So my aim is a 1:1 copy of a freeform via code - I want to duplicate a freeform in the group, and then copy the nodes of the template shape to that freeform.
But how can I get values X2/Y2 and X3/Y3 for the ShapeNodes.Insert-method?
Or any other hints?

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you can't copy the shape you want from within the group and paste it where needed?  Simple example:

```
Dim oGroupShape As Shape
Dim oSh As Shape

Set oGroupShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)

oGroupShape.GroupItems(3).Copy

Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste(1)
```

Comment: Yep, Steve, the shape is pasted, but not inside the group!

Comment: I haven't had a chance to play with this but it might be possible to ungroup the group (keeping a reference to the component bits as a shaperange), then either somehow add the new shape to the shaperange and regroup or select the shaperange then add the new shape to the selection and finally group again.